# How to Serilize a Model when it has Foriegn Key Relation with default User Model in Django

Tags: json, python-3.x, django

**Models.py**
I have Model named Message it has Foriegn Key Realation with default User Model Django .i want to serilize this model.

```
from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from django.conf import settings
      
 class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    content=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username
```

**views.py**

```
from classes.models import ClassRoom,Student
from classes import views
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from chat.models import Message
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers

@login_required
def course_chat_room(request,id):
    course = ClassRoom.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html',{'course':course})

def getMessages(request,id):
    serials = serializers.serialize('json', Message.objects.all().order_by("-id"))
    return JsonResponse(serials, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**
here is my urls of this app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    app_name = 'chat'
    urlpatterns = [
    
        path('room/<int:id>/', views.course_chat_room,name='course_chat_room'),
        path('room/<int:id>/ajax/', views.getMessages,name='getMessages'),
    
]
```

**Result**
when i run this i got the result like this below.i get the author id =10,11,9 etc i want the username instead .how to do this .i know about one technique i.e use_natural_foriegn key but i did not impelemt it in user model in this,because i dont know to to write manager for default user model .The data of message model is saved in database i retrived it in json format .how to solve this .thanks in advance

```
"[{\"model\": \"chat.message\", \"pk\": 37, \"fields\": {\"author\": 10, \"content\": \"hi\", \"timestamp\": \"2021-03-20T03:52:20.863Z\"}}, {\"model\": \"chat.message\", \"pk\": 36, \"fields\": {\"author\": 11, \"content\": \"abdullah\", \"timestamp\": \"2021-03-20T03:06:43.984Z\"}}, {\"model\": \"chat.message\", \"pk\": 35, \"fields\": {\"author\": 9, \"content\": \"hihjhjk\", \"timestamp\": \"2021-03-20T03:06:35.863Z\"}}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** :
use Django Rest Framework for this and I find the solution .
just create a serializers.py and Serilize the Nested models in this way

**serilaizer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from chat.models import Message,User
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), 
        slug_field='username')
        class Meta:
            model=  Message
            fields = ('content','timestamp','author')
```

**views.py**
use @api views of  Django Rest Framework in views.py.api view is just like the function view in Django Rest Framework

```
from django.core import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view 
@api_view(['GET'])
def getMessages(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        messages = Message.objects.all()
        serializer = MessageSerializer(messages, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'chat'

urlpatterns = [

    path('room/<int:id>/', views.course_chat_room,name='course_chat_room'),
    path('room/ajax/', views.getMessages,name='getMessages'),
    
]
```

*This is Json format of data . this is the format of result which i want *

```
 [{"content":"hihjhjk","timestamp":"2021-03-20T03:06:35.863988Z","author":"admin2"},{"content":"abdullah","timestamp":"2021-03-20T03:06:43.984523Z","author":"jani"},{"content":"hi","timestamp":"2021-03-20T03:52:20.863204Z","author":"test"},{"content":"hi","timestamp":"2021-03-21T03:28:29.676668Z","author":"admin2"},{"content":"hi","timestamp":"2021-03-25T00:01:36.914211Z","author":"admin2"}]
```